# How can i combine Guice and Mapstruct?

Tags: java, autowired, jersey-1.0, mapstruct, guice-3

I'm using  jersey and Guice DI and I want to use Mapstruct interfaces
with `@Inject` annotation. 
So is there some way to force Guice to autowire Mapstruct interface implementations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the implementations of the Mappers to be annotated with JSR 330 annotation by using `@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")`. You can find more information in the [`reference documentation`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection).

You can then bind the Mapper interface with the implementation class in your modules.

One way to bind them is to use Guice [Linked Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/LinkedBindings):

```
bind(MyDtoMapper.class).to(MyDtoMapperImpl.class)
```

Another way to bind them is to use [Instance Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings):

```
bind(MyDtoMapper.class).toInstance(MyDtoMapper.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: Thanks @filip for fast respond ! `componentModel = "jsr330"` really handy thing. It adds  `@javax.inject.Named` and `@javax.inject.Singleton` to mapper implementation but when I'm trying to Inject it using setter like this `@Inject 
void setBeanMapper(@Named BeanMapper beanMapper) {
this.beanMapper = beanMapper; 
}`
 it tries to find implementation for BeanMapper annotated with `@com.google.inject.name.Named(value=)` and it fails =(
 Have you any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: I don't have much experience with guice, maybe we need to add an example for a setup with guice. Which `@Inject` and `@Named` are you using in your setter? Maybe guice does not work with mixed annotations, maybe they need to come from `javax.inject` as well.

Comment: hi could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770274/how-to-inject-guice-dependency-in-mapstruct-interface-java i tried but cant able to inject correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ran into issues with using Guice and the jsr330 componentModel, though I don't recall what they were exactly. My use case was a bit more complex because I needed to pass in another service to a mapper decorator as well.  Should work for your simple case as well. Ended up doing provider methods in the Guice Module, like so:

```
public YourModule  extends AbstractModule {
    //With Decorator
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    FooMapper providesFooMapper(RequiredService requiredSvc) {
        FooMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(FooMapper.class);
        ((FooMapperDecorator) mapper).setRequiredService(requiredSvc);
        return mapper;
    }

    //Simple Mapper with no dependencies
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    BarMapper providesBarMapper() {
        return Mappers.getMapper(BarMapper.class);
    }
}
```

Works without a hitch, though I would like for the simple case to be handled by MapStruct cleanly at some point. I'll also note that I only use constructor injection; should work the same for setter injection but YMMV.

Comment: There is already an open issue to support constructor and / or field injection in MapStruct. Follow [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/571) issue if you want to track the status.

Answer (score 0):

Thx [@Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115491/filip%22@Filip%22). So yeah `@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")` almost made all work only thing I had to create binding for each mapper that I use directly in my code `bind(MyDtoMapper.class).toInstance(MyDtoMapper.INSTANCE)` and INSTANCE is declared in MyDtoMapper interface this way: `MyDtoMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( MyDtoMapper.class );`

Comment: I update my answer with your example and the Linked Bindings from Guice. I would prefer to use that as the `Mappers` from MapStruct are thought to be used with the default implementation