# How to inject guice dependency in mapstruct interface - java

Tags: java, mapstruct

My objects

```
 Public void Student(){
     private string name;
     private int age;
 }

Public void ClassRoom(){
   private string roomNo;
   private Student student; //Student Object
}

Public void School(){
   private string roomNo;
   private String student; //String student
}
```

I have an interface

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface TestjkMapper {

    @Named("convertObjToString")
    static String convertObjToString(Student student) {
        return new Gson.tojson(student)
    }

   @Mapping(source = "student", target = "student",qualifiedByName = "convertObjToString")
   School mapClassRoomToSchool(@NonNull ClassRoom classRoom);

}
```

I am planning to inject that gson instead of new Gson()

As per this [How can i combine Guice and Mapstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369852/how-can-i-combine-guice-and-mapstruct)

I tried to make changes but not sure where to add that

```
@Inject
Gson gson
```

I tried like this

```
public interface TestjkMapper {

  @Inject
  Gson gson

    @Named("authorityToMap")
    static Map authorityToMap(Authority authority) {
        return gson.tojson(authority.tostring())
    }

}
```

I am getting compiler error as below

```
variable gson might not have been initialized
```

how to inject correctly inside that interface

Here also

```
bind(TestjkMapper.class).to(TestjkMapperImpl.class)
```

TestjkMapper - My interface

TestjkMapperImpl - This is generated at runtime. So not sure how to bind this

Exact question:

How to convert Student `object` to Student `String` using guice injected `gson`

Comment: wich object you want to map , Authority  ? can you put exemple of input/output

Comment: @AzzabiHaythem : Added example

Comment: the only solution wich worked for me is , @Autowired Gson gson = new Gson();  :(

Comment: isnt it same as  new Gson()

Comment: yes it is the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom injected components in your mappers you will need to use abstract classes instead of interfaces. You can't inject fields into interfaces.

In your example it will look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE, builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public abstract class TestjkMapper {

    @Inject
    Gson gson;

    @Named("convertObjToString")
    static String convertObjToString(Student student) {
        return gson.tojson(student)
    }

   @Mapping(source = "student", target = "student", qualifiedByName = "convertObjToString")
   School mapClassRoomToSchool(@NonNull ClassRoom classRoom);

}
```